# How to get a list of MipMap surfaces from a d3d10 texture2d

Tags: textures, direct3d, mipmaps, geometry-surface, direct3d10

In D3D10 there is a method I can use for getting back a single surface from a Texture2D with one mipmap lvl.

```
{
IDXGISurface* surface;
texture2D->QueryInterface(__uuidof(IDXGISurface), (LPVOID*)&surface);
}
```

But this will not work with a texture that has more then one mipmap, So how can I get back all the surfaces from the mipmap chain ??

Comment: IDXGIResource1::CreateSubresourceSurface(index) can be used to obtain mipmap surface. I'm not sure if D3D10 texture is IDXGIResource1, but D3D11 is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't.  If you want to get at the specific pixel data you will need to use map (if you can).  If you need an IDXGISurface then you'll simply have to not use mipmapping.

Comment: Ok well tnx, for the clarification. I'm disappointed D3D10 would not expose the mipmap surface chain like D3D9. Thats fine, I can get my stuff to work without it.